# How to control VM traffic on KVM

Tags: networking, virtualization, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization

I have multiple VMs running on a KVM hypervisor. One of the VMs is consuming most of the available bandwidth, making it difficult for other VMs to use. How can I control the bandwidth usage for each VM. I would like to guarantee bandwidth for each individual VM. I would like to know if this is usually done on a hypervisor level, if so how? or on a virtual switch level provided that I have one.

Answer (score 6):

The libvirt domain specification includes this functionality already. You can specify separate settings for incoming and outgoing traffic. The example given in the libvirt documentation is:

```
<devices>
  <interface type='network'>
    <source network='default'/>
    <target dev='vnet0'/>
    <bandwidth>
      <inbound average='1000' peak='5000' floor='200' burst='1024'/>
      <outbound average='128' peak='256' burst='256'/>
    </bandwidth>
  </interface>
<devices>
```

You can read more upstream at http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementQoS

Answer (score 0):

Depending how the VMs are networked (bridged vs routed), you might be able to use [tc(8)](http://lartc.org/manpages/tc.txt) in the host to provide priority queuing.

There is a [full howto available](http://www.lartc.org/howto/).

Answer (score 0):

While this might be overkill, I think it may be worth looking into [Open vSwitch](http://openvswitch.org/). It is a software switch that uses OpenFlow to provide Layer 2 and Layer 3 functions. This includes routing and QoS.  You may have better luck with tc, I just wanted to make sure you were aware of this.